# Totally Disable JMeter Cache

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a few JSON APIs against strong stress. However, at one point the "Trend" of increasing response times plateaus. It increases to a very high point and then goes down into a response time that never changes.

I have tried unticking all both JMeter cache manager options, and set the max cache size to one. Also added an HTTP header that the max life on Cache-Control is zero.

How do I totally disable caching in JMeter?

Note :

I searched for relevant posts : however, what comes up is designing JMeter to act like a browser. I am trying to do the total opposite.

Comment: you sure it is caching on Jmeter side? You don't see any requests hit your server? I haven't ever experienced that.

Comment: I see it hits my server every single time and no 304s return. However, I find this plateau very very bizaare and I thought it might be JMeter caching it up.

Comment: Yeah - weird.  I don't use the cache manager in my tests currently. And haven't see results like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no caching unless you use HTTP Cache Manager.

Your issue might be due to overwhelmed server responding with either request rejection or wrong response that takes few seconds to compute.
Or you might be hitting a bandwidth limiter or firewall.

Check by adding assertion that your responses are correct.

if everything is ok then you just might be having a server cache, so response times degrade until cache is filled up.