# How to instruct Jmeter to always get the fresh data from server and not to use cached data

Tags: caching, jmeter

In my testing, UserToken is always getting cached in Jmeter. I tried with cache-manager by checking the checkbox of "clear cache each iteration". But it didnt work. 
How to instruct Jmeter to get the fresh data on each execution from server and not to use it from the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the cache manager and no response will be cached.

If issue persists, give more infos on your issue and token, where it is created, how you extract it ...

Comment: I removed cache manager and tried. Still it doesnt work.My issue is, my application has to get two token, one sessionToken and 2nd one userToken for the logged-in users. After i execute the logout api, the userToken gets deactivated and after this if i execute any user-related api's should give me 401 unauthorized status. But it gives successful status 200 OK even after Logout.

Comment: Any suggestions to this question? It would definitely solve my problem with this caching issue,

Answer (score 0):

Are you totally sure that the token is being really **cached** and it is not hard-coded in your HTTP Request samplers during recording process? If token needs to be dynamic and you send what's had been caught during recording process it may be the cause of errors.

Make sure you properly correlate all the dynamic values. See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide for examples of "csrfmiddlewaretoken" correlation via:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

Comment: Its not record and play script. I wrote script for each HTTP Rest APIs. I have used Regex. The same HTTP rest API's works fine in curl command. But in jmeter execution its becoming an issue. I also found a old post related to it. But no soultion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024900/totally-disable-jmeter-cache

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing network dump of curl and JMeter.